# Updating the Hangman Game with Scaffold Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.7, user-defined-functions

I am currently looking into updating the hangman game to show the scaffold image with a new body part appearing everytime a guessed answer is wrong. I have been told the best way to show the scaffold is by using a 'docstring' in a def function.

in the helpfil tips section on my course it says when the number of the wrond answer is zero, the "empty" scaffold will be displayed, when the number of wrong answers is equal to one, a scaffold with the head added will be displayed etc.

So i have created the def funtion with the docstring of the scaffold but i cant seem to get it to add another body part when the guess is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. New to coding so alot to learn.

```
import random

def displayScaffold(MAX_WRONG):
    stages = ( """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |       /|/
                    |       / /
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |       /|/
                    |       / 
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |       /|/
                    |        
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |       /|
                    |        
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |        |
                    |        
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        o
                    |        
                    |        
                    |
                    ---
               """,
               """
                    ----------
                    |/       |
                    |        
                    |        
                    |        
                    |
                    ---
               """
    )
    return stages[MAX_WRONG]

WORDS = (   "PYTHON", "ESTIMATE", "DIFFICULT", "ANSWER", "XYLOPHONE", \
            "UNNECESSARY", "ADEQUATE", "FEASIBLE", "CHARACTER", \
            "CONGRATULATIONS", "SEQUENCE", "POSITION", "PROGRAM" )
MAX_WRONG = 6;
word = random.choice(WORDS)
so_far = "-" * len(word)
wrong = 0
used = []
print("\nWelcome to the Hangman Game!")
print("\nYou have", MAX_WRONG, "wrong attempts to guess the word.")
print(displayScaffold(MAX_WRONG))

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print("\n", so_far, "\n")
    guess=input("Enter a letter: ")
    guess=guess.upper()
    while guess in used:
        print("\nYou have already guessed this letter\a", guess)
        guess=input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess=guess.upper()
    used.append(guess)
    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes,", guess, "is in the word.")
        new=""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]
        so_far = new
    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.\a")
        wrong += 1
        left = MAX_WRONG - wrong
        print("\nYou have", left, "guesses left.")
if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print("\nYou've been hanged!\a")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!\a")
print("\nThe word was", word)



input("\nPress Enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling `displayScaffold` once when the game starts, not after the user guesses wrong.

Comment: ah so i need to call the function more, especially after they guess wrong ?

Comment: Does everything else look ok ?